# Private NPM Registry with Granular Control

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-package, aws-codeartifact, verdaccio

I am attempting to make a private NPM repository that allows me to make Granular tokens(https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-viewing-access-tokens#creating-granular-access-tokens-on-the-website) which are tokens that allow me to grant access to one package in my private NPM repository. I have attempted to use Verdaccio which doesn't support Granular tokens, npmjs.com which does support granular tokens but doesn't allow them to be created via CLI or API, CodeArtifact and JFrog also don't support Granular Access. Is there a private NPM repository that will allow me to grant granular access to NPM packages?
Thanks